# How can I understand the structure of a sample project

Tags: c#

I am very familiar with C# and Java as I have programmed some research projects without gui. I need now to build a project with graphical user interface and all the standard stuff, meaning localization, versioning, configuration etc. I've started learning each aspect individually, but I've found a good sample open source project that has all the needed capabilities (saving in xml format, reporting etc.). I'm digging into the code, but I'm frustrated of all the automated generated code and I can't filter out the useful information. Where do I start from? It seems that its easier to start clean from the very begining, but is there a way to understand how the sample project has been built? I can add breakpoints and extract some critical functionality but I'm not sure when the code is autogenerated via other means. I want to learn how that sample project is put together. Is there a way to understant it from the finished product and where do I start? Can this sample project be of any use on how I build my own gui having similar functionality? I use the visual studio IDE.

Comment: Have you though about buying a book about Windows Programming in C#, or about `.NET` Forms.

Comment: I've read many beginner books regarding the C# languange syntax and basic windows forms. I'm trying to go to the next level focusing on a real project's GUI concerns.

Comment: Divide and conquer. As you mentioned learn the pieces individually and try to solve one functionality problem at a time. The generated code is of little use, because it is supposed to replace tedious and repeatable coding by humans. The real decisions and design is always in the non-generated code (also known as _programming_).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846221/a-way-to-catch-up-to-modern-programming-techniques

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers. As it is difficult to extract the information on how a GUI of a sample project has been setup, I concluded to this procedure:

1. Finilize my requirements by getting ideas from the sample project.
2. Search information on how each aspect must be setup (localization, configuration etc.).
3. I will probably find more than 1 way to implement each aspect so I'll choose what suits me best.
4. Recognize if my GUI setting up approach is similar to the sample project just to learn more.

Learning how a special functionality of a sample project has been implemented is straightforward by debugging it line by line. I was hoping I could learn GUI aspects like localization from it. But it seems that I first need to learn on how to implement localization with VS and later compare it with the sample project.
I'm sorry about the title, it's probably misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some tips from my own experience dealing with a big project, which has millions of lines of code.

- First, see and try to understand the project architecture, which layers it has, UI, Entity Framework, etc... If you have DB then see the diagram of the tables and try to understand which entities you have, the relations between them, the properties. You can write for yourself a short diagram with the main entities.
- Then you can run the project so you can see what it does, if you have a specification document than first, read it (skimming).
- Then you can see your code, read notes (if exists), read the names of the functions, members, etc... Try to understand a little bit what each function does and who calls it - you can use `F12` keyboard or `Shift + F12` to see the code usages.
- Next step, going dipper, run your project and debug it, this is the best to learn a code, so debug it a lot. Try to understand why each method is called, note also the layer the methods are, for example you debug a code in the UI Layer which calls to a method in the BL (Buisness Logic) layer, so you can understand that it accesses from the client side to the server side.
- If there are some methods that you don't understand, then you can remove some lines or change them and to see the effect when you run the code.
- Don't forget - sometimes the codes are wrong, so always be suspicious.

This may take some time, but if you do those steps then finally you will get it.

Goodluck :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understood the architecture of the sample project and it's business logic. I'm trying to figure out how the gui has been setup and what to look for (localization, configuration settings etc). It seems that it's easier setting it up from my requirements, by learning how every gui control works and not bother with the sample project.

Comment: One more important tip is: don't be afraid of code. Sometimes you see lots of lines of code and it seems to be strange and unclear, ok, just debug it, see what it does, and it can be enough - not always you need to understand the code. By the way, if you like my comment you can mark it as useful :)